# Use Eclipse JDT parser in a Java project

Tags: eclipse, maven, sbt

I have a problem integrating Eclipse JDT in a project.

I added the following dependency to `sbt`

```
libraryDependencies += "org.eclipse.jdt" % "core" % "3.3.0-v_771"
```

but I get the following missing dependencies:

```
[warn]  :: org.eclipse.equinox#app;[1.0.0,2.0.0): not found
[warn]  :: org.eclipse.equinox#common;[3.3.0,4.0.0): not found
```

Is there any repository or any `sbt` configuration I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eclipse JDT jars are on Maven Central so adding new resolvers are not going to help here. (Besides it's now  https://repo.eclipse.org).

According to [org.eclipse.jdt/core](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.eclipse.jdt/core), the latest release version is 3.2.0.666 so try this:

```
libraryDependencies += "org.eclipse.jdt" % "core" % "3.2.0.666"
```

### note

I had to dig around a bit to see why 3.3.0-v_771 doesn't work. Somewhere along the dependencies `org.eclipse.equinox#app;[1.0.0,2.0.0)` is required. The only revision available according to [org.eclipse.equinox/app](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.eclipse.equinox/app) is 1.0.0-v20070606.

Maven's [Dependency Mediation and Conflict Resolution](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/MAVEN/Dependency+Mediation+and+Conflict+Resolution) says:

> if qualifier does not exist, it is newer than if it does

In other words, 1.0.0-v20070606 < 1.0.0, so it doesn't meet the criteria.

Answer (score 0):

The [Maven - Eclipsepedia](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Maven), told us that the Eclipse Maven Repository is  http://maven.eclipse.org/nexus/ Please add it to your pom.

I hope this may help.

Answer (score 0):

You might whant to use the latest version ([3.12.2](https://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.eclipse.jdt%7Corg.eclipse.jdt.core%7C3.12.2%7Cjar)) of JDT core now.

```
libraryDependencies += "org.eclipse.jdt" % "org.eclipse.jdt.core" % "3.12.2"
```

This is a [new approach](https://objectteams.wordpress.com/2017/01/09/eclipse-neon-2-is-on-maven-central/) to plublish the eclipse libs on maven central (simple version numbers, standard maven metadata for dependencies, source artifacts, 3rd party dependencies...). Please report if this is working for you or not.